# Куда уходят данные после создания их функцией add_post_meta?

Tags: база-данных, wordpress, metadata

Куда уходят эти дополнительные поля wp_termmeta, wp_postmeta и wp_usermeta, после того, как они создаются в WordPress?

Допустим, есть функция вида:

```
add_post_meta($postID, $some_name, '0');
```

где `$postID` - это ID поста, `$some_name` - это ключ и 0 это значение по этому ключу. Далее я без проблем смогу получить доступ к созданной мета-информации:

```
get_post_meta($postID, $some_name, true);
```

Но, в базе данных я не могу найти, куда сохраняется указанная информация.
В чем моя ошибка? Куда смотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Целый день ломал голову, задал вопрос сюда и сразу же сам нашел ответ.
Как я все и описал, я был прав.
Указанные метаполя сохраняются в базе данных в таблицах wp_termmeta, wp_postmeta и wp_usermeta. Просто указанные таблицы содержат больше записей, чем могут отобразить за один раз. Чтобы увидеть новые поля требуется перейти на следующую страницу соответствующей таблицы.